# Subscipt out of range first time I run it but doesn't give error on next runs

Tags: vba, excel

I get **"subscript out of range"** error on line:

```
Set DataSheet = Worksheets(DataSheetName)
```

This only happens the first time I run it. If I re-run the code after the error, the macro works fine.

Complete code:

```
Sub iGetData()

Dim ValidatorWB As Workbook
Dim PopDetail As Worksheet
Dim DataSheetName As String
Dim DataWB As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim Ret
Dim DWBName As String
Dim FNOrder As String
Dim FNOrdCol As String

Set PopDetail = Worksheets("PopulateWireframe")
Set ValidatorWB = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
DataSheetName = Range("F18").Value
FNOrder = Range("F33").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Open data file
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen(PopDetail.Range("C18").Value)
If Ret = False Then

Workbooks.Open PopDetail.Range("C18").Value
DataFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set DataWB = Workbooks(DataFileName)
Set DataSheet = Worksheets(DataSheetName)

Dim FilterColumn As String
Dim FilterCriteria As String
Dim ColumnNumber As Integer

'Set filter
With DataSheet
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
End With

ValidatorWB.Activate
PopDetail.Activate

For x = 21 To 30

If Range("E" & x).Value <> "" And Range("F" & x).Value <> "" Then

    FilterColumn = PopDetail.Range("E" & x).Value
    FilterCriteria = PopDetail.Range("F" & x).Value

    DataWB.Activate
    DataSheet.Activate

    DataSheet.Range("A1").Select

    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select

    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Find(What:=FilterColumn, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    ColumnNumber = ActiveCell.Column

    DataSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    DataSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=ColumnNumber, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria

End If

    ValidatorWB.Activate
    PopDetail.Activate

'x = x + 1

Next x

    DataWB.Activate
    DataSheet.Activate

    'Alpahebtical order
    DataSheet.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Find(What:=FNOrder, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    FNOrdCol = ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(FNOrdCol), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange DataSheet.Cells
        .header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    'Copy data
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Paste data to validator
    ValidatorWB.Activate
    ValidatorWB.Sheets.Add().Name = "ValidatorData"
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'DataWB.Close savechanges:=False
If DataWB.Windows(1).Visible = True Then
DataWB.Windows(1).Visible = False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

PopDetail.Activate

Else

DWBName = GetFilenameFromPath(PopDetail.Range("C18").Value)
Set DataWB = Workbooks(DWBName)
DataWB.Activate
Set DataSheet = Worksheets(DataSheetName)
DataSheet.Activate
With DataSheet
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
End With

ValidatorWB.Activate
PopDetail.Activate

For x = 21 To 30

If Range("E" & x).Value <> "" And Range("F" & x).Value <> "" Then

    FilterColumn = PopDetail.Range("E" & x).Value
    FilterCriteria = PopDetail.Range("F" & x).Value

    DataWB.Activate
    DataSheet.Activate

    DataSheet.Range("A1").Select

    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select

    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select

    Selection.Find(What:=FilterColumn, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    ColumnNumber = ActiveCell.Column

    DataSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    DataSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=ColumnNumber, Criteria1:=FilterCriteria

End If

    ValidatorWB.Activate
    PopDetail.Activate

'x = x + 1

Next x

    DataWB.Activate
    DataSheet.Activate

    'Alpahebtical order
    DataSheet.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Find(What:=FNOrder, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    FNOrdCol = ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(FNOrdCol), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange DataSheet.Cells
        .header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    'Copy data
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Paste data to validator
    ValidatorWB.Activate
    ValidatorWB.Sheets.Add().Name = "ValidatorData"
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'DataWB.Close savechanges:=False
If DataWB.Windows(1).Visible = True Then
DataWB.Windows(1).Visible = False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

PopDetail.Activate

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Check my comment in your previous question about this very same code line.

Comment: I still get the same error when I do Set DataSheet = DataWB.Worksheets(DataSheetName). I tried that before I posted here.

Comment: Please take note what I mentioned in this post: This only happens the first time I run it. If I re-run the code after the error, the macro works fine.

Comment: Your code has the line `Set DataSheet = Worksheets(DataSheetName)` twice. Which ones causes the error? As @Jeeped says you should qualify the `Worksheets(DataSheetName)` with the workbook reference. Using `ActiveSheet` is risky when your code *sometimes* opens another workbook.

Comment: The very first one causes the error. I'll play around with my code but let me know if you see anything. I'll post updates here as well. I know that my code isn't efficient but at least it's easily readable. This was my first coding project in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. Excel usually sets a newly opened workbook as the active workbook which is why I used activeworkbook.name to define a workbook but the newly opened workbook was not being set as the active workbook.

Did this:

```
Workbooks.Open PopDetail.Range("C18").Value
DataFileName = GetFilenameFromPath(PopDetail.Range("C18").Value)
Set DataWB = Workbooks(DataFileName)
DataWB.Activate
Set DataSheet = Worksheets(DataSheetName)
```

Instead of:

```
Workbooks.Open PopDetail.Range("C18").Value
DataFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Set DataWB = Workbooks(DataFileName)
Set DataSheet = Worksheets(DataSheetName)
```

GetFilename Code:

```
Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
' Returns the rightmost characters of a string upto but not including the rightmost '\'
' e.g. 'c:\winnt\win.ini' returns 'win.ini'

    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```